# Tekton Dashboard OIDC

Tags: openid-connect, tekton, tekton-pipelines

Is there a supported way to enable OIDC with Tekton dashboard? I found this link:

https://medium.com/octo-technology-morocco/secure-authentication-to-tekton-dashboard-using-oidc-36de9b3f8a7d

which describes a custom way of doing it. But I'd prefer not to have to create a separate custom deployment for this. If there's a way to modify the out of box ingress/deployment/service that would be very much preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Tekton dashboard doesn't implement authentication. You'll want to setup a proxy (oauth-proxy, apache, ... whatever fits best with your identity provider).

Comment: If you are not to fine with custom way, you can do it using RBAC but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable authentication to your Tekton dashboard using GitHub and OAuthProxy2 easily. You can refer to this [article](https://codingtricks.io/add-authentication-to-tekton-dashboard/)